# How to decrement product quantity after checkout in Laravel (With Session)

Tags: laravel, session, laravel-5, shopping-cart

Can you help me how to decrement after doing a checkout. So far this is the only idea I have but it shows an error called "Object of class Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection could not be converted to number
". Thank you for the reply. Also I am using the one with session.
[image]
[image]

Note. I edit and put another image for more clearer explanation and here is the code

```
public function postCheckout(Request $request){
        $books = Product::all();
        if (!Session::has('cart')){
             return view('shop.shoppingcart');

        }
        $oldCart = Session::get('cart');
        $cart = new Cart($oldCart);
        $order = new Order();
        $order->cart = serialize($cart);
        $order->address = $request->input('address');
        $order->name = $request->input('name');
        
        Auth::user()->orders()->save($order);
        
        $q=$cart->totalQty;
        $r=$books-$q;
      Product::table('books')
      ->where('id',$id) 
    
      ->update(array('quantity' => $r));
        Session::forget('cart');

        return redirect("home");
    }
```

And the error is "Object of class Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection could not be converted to number"

Comment: it should be "  $books = Product::all();" but it shows an error called "Object of class Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection could not be converted to number
"

Comment: Welcome to SO ... please do not put up pictures of code, code is text

Comment: @AndySong Ok ill start adding another pic to make it clearer

Comment: The one thing I put now has a $book = Product::all() and shows an error "Object of class Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection could not be converted to number". Sorry dont know how to upload an image (idk if stackover has a function of it) in the comment

Comment: yes please that so will be more easy if you push your code here :)

Comment: done uploading the code

Answer (score 0):

You have this line of code:

```
    $books = Product::all();
```

Here, `$books` is a collection.

And after a few lines, this one:

```
    $r=$books-$q;
```

which of course can't execute without error because you're trying to subtract a number from a collection.

I assume you don't actually want the whole book collection, but the number of books. In that case, replace `$books = Product::all();` with  `$books = Product::count();` and your code should work fine.

However, that line counts *all* the books, and I guess you only want to decrease the quantity of the *purchased* books. Unfortunately, that's not what you code does. For example, in this code:

```
  Product::table('books')
      ->where('id',$id) 
      ->update(array('quantity' => $r));
```

where does the `$id` variable come from? You don't set its value anywhere. What you should do is iterate every item of your cart, get the ID and quantity of each item, and perform an update query for each item.